# Error when asking for username with Facebook authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

When my users sign up, I want them to have a user name as well. In the user schema, there is a username field that is required and unique. However, when a user registers with Facebook through passport, this field can't be entered, so it throws me an error.

The only solution I came up with was assigning them a random username at signup and then asking them for a real one after, but that doesn't seem like the best idea.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using passport for local authentication of are you using the Twitter (or other social media) login?

Comment: Both. Obviously I can ask for a username for local auth, but when it comes to Facebook auth, not everyone has a username I can use.

Comment: Indeed. I do not think there is another option than asking for a username after the login.

Comment: why can't the field be entered? pls show us your passport implementation.

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue on the [passport Github repository](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues) to ask the authors for a solution directly and then share it with us...

Comment: Apparently your issue is related only with social media authentications (Facebook), so I modified your question accordingly to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am hearing you want to store the username with your facebook info.

You need to add add `passReqToCallback: true`

```html
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    consumerKey: FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: FACEBOOK_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://www.example.com/auth/twitter/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
     ...
    Store in database
  }
));
```

the user info would be stored in the req.body object